# Best way to use a single logger in my python project, overwrite root logger or replace import everywhere?

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

Title is a bit vague but I think my code examples make it clear. I want to start using a custom logger in a large project of mine.

Currently, in every file that I use logging, I import logging and use that like this:

```
# file A
import logging

logging.info(...)
```

I do this in many files. I want to use my own specific logger:

```
# __init__.py

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger!')
```

There are two approaches I think to using this logger everywhere in my project:

Option 1:
Importing the logger defined above in all of my files instead of the logging module:

```
# file A
from ... import logger

logger.info(...)
```

Option 2: Overriding the root logger, so that I do not have to replace anything

```
# __init_
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger!')
logging.root = logger
```

Now I do not have to replace the imports in all my files. What is the best option and why?

Comment: Are you asking how to replace the root logger with a different custom logger in every module, or just how to configure the root logger once?

Comment: If the root logger is the only logger you plan on using, just configure it appropriately. There's no real reason to create a second logger to use exclusively.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the comment! I want to add a handler (Azure Application Insight) so I think I need to create one

Comment: You can add a handler to the root logger. There is nothing special about the root logger except that any other logger will inherit its configuration.

Answer (score 1):

`getLogger('foo')` always returns the same `Logger` instance, no matter where it is called. (Loggers have their own global "namespace" managed by the module itself.)

Wherever you want to use `my_logger`, just use

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
```

It's the job of the *application* to ensure that the logger named `my_logger` is configured correctly on startup.

Comment: That means I have to add that to each file right? (akin to option 2)

Comment: Yes; you just don't have to replace the root logger. (You'll use `logger.info(...)` instead of `logging.info(...)`, but that's probably a change for the better.)